# How can display uploaded DOC file in admin grid using ui component in magento2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to display uploaded file in admin edit form using ui component in magento2

How Can i Get this?

[image]

and here is **fildset.php**

```
     <?php  
        namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form;


     use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;  
     use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;  
      use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\FieldFactory;  
     use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset as BaseFieldset;

     class Fieldset extends BaseFieldset  
    {

      private $fieldFactory;

     public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
         array $components = [],
  array $data = [],
  FieldFactory $fieldFactory,
  \Vendor\Module\Model\Projectsubmit $modelProjectsubmit,
  \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
  \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface  $storeManager   
           )
      {
            parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
            $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
            $this->_request = $request;
          $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       }


       public function getChildComponents()
      {

      $fields=$this->getFields();

         foreach ($fields as $k => $fieldConfig) {

        $fieldInstance = $this->fieldFactory->create();
      $name = $fieldConfig['name'];

      $fieldInstance->setData(
          [
              'config' => $fieldConfig,
              'name' => $name
          ]
      );

      $fieldInstance->prepare();
      $this->addComponent($name, $fieldInstance);
  }
    $this->_coreSession->setMaincategory('');
    $this->_coreSession->setChildcategory('');
  return parent::getChildComponents();
         }


     function getFields(){
  $id=$this->_request->getParam('projectsubmit_id');

  $getCategoryData=$this->_modelProjectsubmit->getCollection()->getData();
  foreach($getCategoryData as $key=>$value){
      if($value['projectsubmit_id']==$id)
      {
          $mainCategory=$value['main_category'];
          $childCategory=$value['child_category'];
          $uploadFile=$value['upload_file'];
      }

  }
  $after_html='';

    if($uploadFile != '')
    {
      $result = explode(",",$uploadFile);    
      foreach ($result as $value)
      {
          $path = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."product-popup/".$value;

          // $after_html.= '<a href="'.$path.'" target ="_blank">
          //             <img height="22" width="22" class="small-image-preview v-middle" alt="'.$value.'" title="'.$value.'" id="slider" src="'.$path.'"/></a>';
      }
    }

  $formFields = $this->_modelProjectsubmit->defineFormFields();

    $currentform = $formFields[$mainCategory][$childCategory];  

    foreach($currentform as $key => $formfield) :  
    if(!(isset($formfield['type']))) 
    continue; 


      if($formfield['type'] == "text") {
         $fields[]= [
                'label'     => strip_tags($formfield['label']),
                'disabled'  => true,
                'name'      => $formfield['key'],
                'formElement' => 'input',
          ];  
          } 
      elseif($formfield['type'] == "radio") {


          if($formfield['key'] == "color_preferences") {
         $fields[]= [
                'label'     => 'Color Preferences',
                'disabled'  => true,
                'name'      => 'color_preferences',
                'formElement' =>'input',
          ]; 

          }
           else
          {
               $fields[]= [
                'label'     => strip_tags($formfield['label']),
                'disabled'  => true,
                'name'      => $formfield['key'],
                'formElement' =>'select',
                'options'    => $options,
            ]; 

                   // die("<br> in".__FILE__." : ".__LINE__);

         }
       if(isset($formfield['extratype']) && $formfield['extratype'] == "text") {
               $fields[]= [
                'label'     => "Other Info",
                'disabled'  => true,
                'name'      => $formfield['extrakey'],
                'formElement' =>'input',
            ]; 
       }
 }
   elseif($formfield['type'] == "textarea") {
          $fields[]= [
                'label'     => strip_tags($formfield['label']),
                'disabled'  => true,
                'name'      => $formfield['key'],
                'formElement' =>'textarea',
            ];  
    }
     **$fields[]= [
                'label'     => 'File',
                'disabled'  => true,
                'name'      => 'upload_file',
                'formElement' =>'fileUploader',
                'url' => $after_html
            ];**    ***(i need to set my all logic here)***

    endforeach;
    return $fields;

     }
         }
```

> **$fields[]= [
>                   'label'     => 'File',
>                   'disabled'  => true,
>                   'name'      => 'upload_file',
>                   'formElement' =>'fileUploader',
>                   'url' => $after_html
>               ];** please check this part

Comment: Can you please explain more or attach screenshot ?

Comment: @RohanHapani PLease check attached. I am creating this form with dynamic content.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Have you checked reference module in my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below sample image upload module to achieve your things. i think this module is fit to your requirement.

[Magento 2 sample module demonstrating how to upload an image file within a grid and form UI Component.](https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-sample-imageuploader)

I hope it helps.

**Note:** Here i give you sample module so you can take a reference and build your module or customize your module.

Comment: Yes but it's the different case.
I am generating form dynamically

Comment: Dynamic means, can you explain more?

Comment: i have added fieldset.php file that hoe m i generating dynamic form field